# String Expected error in find statment

Tags: jquery

I use this jquery code into `script` tag .I get **Expected string** error.What is problem?

```
if ($('#NumberPassenger').val() == 6 && $(btn).closest('article').find("span:contains(کوپه ای 4)").size() == 1) {
                    $('#Modal').modal('show');
                    $('#Modal .messageDanger').text('توجه!! امکان انتخاب کوپه ای 4 نفره برای شما میسر نیست .');
                    return;
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

contains needs a string as an argument.

Enclose you text within single quotes as

```
find("span:contains('کوپه ای 4')")
```

complete Jquery

```
if ($('#NumberPassenger').val() == 6 && $(btn).closest('article').find("span:contains('کوپه ای 4')").size() == 1) {
                    $('#Modal').modal('show');
                    $('#Modal .messageDanger').text('توجه!! امکان انتخاب کوپه ای 4 نفره برای شما میسر نیست .');
                    return;
                }
```